# Connecting to Geth private network from Metamask using RPC URL

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, rpc, geth, metamask

I have created a private chain in Geth which is running in `machine1`. I want to connect to the private chain running in `machine1` from `machine2's` Metamask using rpc. `machine1` and `machine2` are connected to the same Wifi network.

The IP address of `machine1` is 192.168.0.103 and I am opening port number 8501 for RPC connections.

The following are the flags that I have used to start Geth in `machine1`:

```
geth --datadir "C:\Users\smuth\Desktop\GETH DAPP POA\node1" --port 30311 --http --http.addr "192.168.0.103" --http.port 8501 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api "personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner" --networkid 1515 console --ipcdisable --nat extip:192.168.0.103
```

I tried using the rpc url http://192.168.0.103:8501 and chain ID as 1515 in Metamask of `machine2`. But Metamask doesn't connect and displays the error : "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?"
The console log of Metamask displays a timed out HTTP POST request to the RPC URL (http://192.168.0.103:8501)

What could be changed to make this connection work?

Comment: Likely the `machine1` firewall is blocking incoming connections on the port `8501`

Comment: Yes that was the problem @PetrHejda. I changed the inbound, outbound rules for 8501 port and its working! Thanks!